# has_many Using class Versus class_name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been modelling some custom `has_many` associations like this:

```
has_many :friends, class: User
```

I recently found that this style isn't documented and the API docs:

```
has_many :friends, class_name: 'User'
```

I haven't noticed any problems with the former syntax, and I'm curious why the later syntax is used (wouldn't it be better to avoid converting the string to a class?). Any reason to switch from the former to the later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well in coming version of *rails* `class` has been [renamed to `anonymous_class`](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/19659). Although it is still in the *master* branch. There is a problem with the use of `:class` and here it goes from the [*commit*](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/1119c89297f793b1b75f9ac1ecde280729118768) :

> In 1f006c an option was added called :class to allow passing anonymous
>   classes to association definitions. Since using :class instead of
>   :class_name is a fairly common typo even amongst experienced developers
>   this can result in hard to debug errors arising in raise_on_type_mismatch?
>
> To fix this we're renaming the option from :class to :anonymous_class as
>   that is a more correct description of what the option is for. Since this
>   was an internal, undocumented option there is no need for a deprecation.

It is in [4-2-stable](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activerecord/CHANGELOG.md)

> Rename `:class` to `:anonymous_class` in association options. Fixes #19659

Answer (score 0):

If you needed to define a class dynamically or run a method that would return a class then the first option would be useful.

Honestly though I can't think of a good scenario in which that would be an ideal approach.

Comment: We've found this a great solution in cases where a "reverse polymorphism" is desired.  A class for example that only cares about certain methods being implemented on relationships, and doesn't care about whether they are all the same class.  These related classes we have a sort of Interface on to ensure the method is implemented